# Connect to SQL Server database by passing a different set of windows auth credentials in the python scripts

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I want to connect to a database by connecting as a different user using Python script and by using the Windows authentication method.

```
import pyodbc

server = 'server_name'  # Replace with your server name or IP address
database = 'database_name'  # Replace with your database name
trusted_connection = 'yes'  # Use 'yes' for Windows Authentication
password = r'password'
username = 'username'
try:
    connection = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')

    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    # connection.close()

except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error connecting to the database:", e)
```

When I run the script, it takes the current Windows credentials, and I want to pass different credentials so that I can access the instance

I was expecting to access this using different user cred, but when I run the scripts it uses the default Windows credentials.

Comment: You can't pass windows credentials like that are SQL Authentication credentials. If you want to connect using a different Windows user, you need to *run* the application as that user.

Comment: Also you don't "connect to SSMS"; SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is an IDE-like application. Your connecting to a database engine, presumably SQL Server?

Comment: so I have been provided with below details
server = 'server_name'  
database = 'database_name'  
trusted_connection = 'yes'  
password = 'password'
username = 'username'
how can i connect with SQL server using these. the normal way of connecting to SQL is not working

Comment: @ThomA i always get error saying login failed for user

Comment: Yes, you likely are, because you're attempting to pass *Windows* credentials as SQL Authentication credentials; they are *completely* different authentication protocols. You *cannot* pass Windows credentials with Username and Password properties, it's a Trusted Connected ***OR*** Username and password.

Comment: @ThomA is there is some way to pass different windows credentials?

Comment: *"If you want to connect using a different Windows user, you need to run the application as that user."*

Comment: i created another process and tried to run the scripts using runas but this also doesn't work.
@ThomA are you saying i need to login into windows with those credentials first?

Comment: you need to remove the user / pwd parts from connectionstring anyways. Doesn't work is a bad way of describing your issue. runas should work but maybe your credentials are wrong

Comment: i double checked my cred, by connecting to SQL server as different user directly through the tool with those creds, and it worked. but when i try to connect through script i get an error that username or password is wrong. @siggemannen

Comment: you mean you logged out from your windows user and logged on with those other credentials?

Comment: No. so if you press shift key and click on the SSMS tool, you can run that application as different users. now if i try accessing the database like this it works with the same credentials @siggemannen

Comment: So what connection string are you using now for pyodbc? You probably want `DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};Trusted_Connection=yes;` notice there is no user or password, but `Trusted_Connection=yes;` is specified

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using pyodbc and `create_engine` from sqlachemy, as this does not even require you to specify a password. I don't think it's safe putting plain text in a code:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://<server_name>/<database_name>?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server+Native+Cleint+11.0')
```

Comment: Why use the Native Client? That was deprecated in 2012 and doesn't support versions of SQL Server after 2014. It doesn't even ship with SQL Server 2022+ anymore.

Comment: I have used this in SQL Server 2018 and it works. Not sure about 2022, I will test that to confirm, well noted

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2018... There were release in 2017 and 2019 but not in 2018.

Comment: I just confirmed using Select @@Version, and it is actually MS SQL 2019, I was only connecting to it using 2018 SSMS. And I am certain I used Native Client on it and it worked. Although I read an article online that confirmed that it has been deprecated. I need to R&D on the new mode and update my code accordingly.

Comment: i was able to establish a connection successfully using sqlalchemy, @Ifeoluwa how can i use this engine to query a table?

Comment: It's SSMS *18* not SSMS 2018...

Comment: @Ifeoluwa i query the table, but got an error connection timesout. not sure if this works. Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: But do you get the point? @ThomA

Comment: My point remains; using Native Client (or as you have it, Native "cleint") is the wrong driver here.